# Correct detect cell in row before breaking page in table

Tags: cals

For my task I use Cals package. I create table spread for many pages with row breaking at the end of pages. In this package It describes row dispatch. But It works only rows, and doesn't detect cell in which break happens. When new page started, content always inserted to the first cell even so breaking actions took place in the second cell. The main problem how to right detect in which cell breaks row and how to typeset content to the right cell. Does this package allow to split row to cells at the end of the page and correct start row (include cells )in next page?

Code:

```
\makeatletter
\let\oldDispatch=\cals@row@dispatch
\newbox\rowBefore
\newbox\rowAfter

\newbox\decorationCopy
\newdimen\splitHeight

\def\cals@row@dispatch{%
\cals@ifbreak\iftrue
  \splitHeight=\pagegoal \advance\splitHeight -\pagetotal
  \ifdim \splitHeight>50pt % break inrow only if at least 100pt left
    \advance\splitHeight -5pt
    \setbox\rowBefore=\hbox{}
    \setbox\rowAfter=\hbox{}
    \def\next{%
     \setbox0=\lastbox
      \ifvoid0
        \def\next{\global\setbox\rowBefore=\box\rowBefore
                  \global\setbox\rowAfter=\box\rowAfter

                                    }%
      \else
        \setbox2=\vsplit0 to\splitHeight
        \setbox\rowBefore=\hbox{\box2 \unhbox\rowBefore}%
        \setbox\rowAfter=\hbox{\box0 \unhbox\rowAfter}%
      \fi
      \next}
   \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox\cals@current@row \next}

    \setbox\decorationCopy=\copy\cals@current@cs
    \setbox\cals@current@row=\box\rowBefore
    \ht\cals@current@cs=\ht\cals@current@row
    \oldDispatch
    \cals@issue@break

    \setbox\cals@current@row=\box\rowAfter
    \cals@reheight@cells\cals@current@row
    \setbox\cals@current@cs=\box\decorationCopy

    %   

    \ht\cals@current@cs=\ht\cals@current@row
   %\let\cals@current@context=b
  \fi
\fi
\oldDispatch}

\begin{myenv}
\colwidths{{6.6cm}{10.97cm}}
\hrule width\hsize \vskip0pt
\brow \cell {\vspace{-15pt} \subsubsection{Very long text}}\cell { Very long text
} \erow
\end{myenv}
```

Comment: Without the complete working example, it is impossible to say anything.

Comment: Working example is completely the same as you advice me http://uucode.com/download/2010/12/inrow_break/test.tex. But I need to adapt this code to my need (first cell continues in first cell next page, The second is repeat the same) and crashed with problems questions descried below

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by using a newer version of a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the code, a new version should do what desired:

http://uucode.com/download/2013/inrowbrk.tex

But I still consider your idea is very dangerous. Table should not be split inside a cell.

Comment: Could you explain the consequences of such breaking? I try your code and it works fine as I need. But when I insert my text instead [lipsum] Its unable to split first cell in column if It doesn't fit to page. It works only for the second one.

Comment: @Lopes 1) The code ``cals@row@dispatch`` does not work for rows with straddled cells. 2) The decision if a break is required is based on remaining vertical size on the page. So, the page-breaking mechanism of TeX or other packages, which use it, might be confused.

3) Send me your code, I'll look at it.

Comment: I attached under comment